# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input on line one

Tags: javascript, html, syntax, syntax-error

This error is usually associated with messy close parens, but I'm getting the error on **line 1** of the file!

Here's the javascript`(filename: calculate.js)`

```
var colors = new Array();
colors["SILVER"]    = -2;
...
```

There's plenty more code later in the file, but I don't think it could be causing this error.

And in case this is caused by the head declarations, here's the document head.

```
<meta id="author" content="Dawson Diaz, Evan Shimoniak">
<meta id="description" content="Resistor Color Code Calculator">
<meta id="keywords" content="Resistor, Calculator, Color Code, Electronics">
<!--Set favicon-->
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<!--Include jQuery-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest Bootstrap minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<!--Latest compiled and minified Bootsrap JavaScript-->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Calculator-->
<script src="calculate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Input processing-->
<script src="ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The full code for calculate.js is [here](https://github.com/dawsondiaz/R3C/blob/24ddf57c586c7fa74b6c18cbe35f1b3f5da0b02d/calculate.js)

Comment: I cam not getting the [error](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/B43JE/). Perhaps, you could put the whole code in a fiddle.

Comment: I'll do one better, here's the [full page URL](http://dawsondiaz.github.io/R3C/)

Comment: you need one closing brace for the method getResistanceStr()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `}` at the end of your `getResistanceStr` function.  Don't know why it says line 1 but that is the problem.